# Bootstrap 4 ломает стили в админке Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

При использовании известного фреймворка **Bootstrap 4** и **Wordpress**, Bootstrap "ломает" некоторые стили в админке, и выглядит это мягко говоря не очень (пример ниже).

Возможно-ли загрузить стили bootstrap до того, как загрузятся стили панели администрирования Wordpress?

Т.е. до того, как выведется это:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost/wp-admin/load-styles.php...
```

Такой способ не работает:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'load_first', 1 );
```

Аналогичные проблемы и с некоторыми другими популярными фреймворками, например: **UIkit**, **Bulma**. Если бы стили Bootstrap загрузились раньше стилей панели администрирования, то по логике стили Wordpress стали бы приоритетней и ситуация исправилась.

Или здесь нужен другой подход к решению данной проблемы?

Пример:
[image: bootstrap 4 и админка wordpress]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*admin_enqueue_scripts* - с установленной приоритизацией загружает стили **Bootstrap** раньше стилей админ панели **Wordpress**, теперь верстка админки не "едет". Хотя все не так идеально, как хотелось бы.

*wp_head* - загружает стили фреймворка, но уже на сайте.

```
define('THEME_URL', get_template_directory_uri());

function framework_load_first(){
    $url = THEME_URL;

    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' id='Framework_Bootstrap'
        href='{$url}/public/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />";
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', "framework_load_first", 1);
add_action( 'wp_head', 'framework_load_first',1);
```

Пример, как Bootstrap ведет себя после использования данного метода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фреймворк **UIkit** - теперь тоже работает с админкой штатно, но **Bulma** фреймворк все еще ломает некоторые стили. Видимо для Bulma нужны особые методы.